# Regex extraction of first / last occurrence

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract contents between first { and last }

```
{"Command":{"Version": "1.1","Body":{}}}
```

I tried this regex, why it doesn't work, no match found.

```
^\\{(.*?)\\}$
```

can you help ?

Comment: Use `(?s)^\\{(.*)\\}$`

Comment: Nah. But [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) might.

Comment: Why regex? This is, normally, doable with simpler language functions.

Comment: @Slavic, can you please show your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in MS RegEx:

```
 var regEx = "\\{{1}?(.*)\\}{1}?";
```

It looks for the first (lazy) instance of {, then gets all characters until a greedy "}".  Keep in mind, if you have:

`{<stuffYouWant>}{<stuffYouWant>}` on a single line...

you will get:

`<stuffYouWant>}{<stuffYouwant>` in a single grab.

NOTE: yours doesn't work because you are looking for all characters `(.*)` that don't have a `{`, but also has a `}`.  it needs a place to start, otherwise it will grab everything until the last `}` and then see that it has `{` and disqualify that grab.